# Запись бинарных данных в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно закодировать файл, и раскодировать его.
Пример:

> Закодированное сообщение:
> \xff\xd8\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x06\x04\x05\x06\x05\x04\x06\x06\x05\x06\x07\x07\x06\x08\n\xff\xd8\xff\xdb
> C \x06\x04\x05\x06\x05\x04\x06\x06\x05\x06\x07\x07\x06\x08\n'(44
> байта) Раскодированное сообщение:
> x80\x03]q\x00(K\xffK\xd8K\xffK\xdbKCK\x06K\x04K\x05K\x06K\x05K\x04K\x06K\x06K\x05K\x06K\x07K\x07K\x06K\x08K\nK\xffK\xd8K\xffK\xd
> bK KCK
> K\x06K\x04K\x05K\x06K\x05K\x04K\x06K\x06K\x05K\x06K\x07K\x07K\x06K\x08K\ne.
> (92 байта)

Дело в том, что я записываю раскодированное сообщение с помощью коллекции. Может ли она влиять на то, как записываются данные?

Кодирование битов:

```
f = open('s.dat', 'rb')
for line in f:
    print(line)
    for c in line:#считывание строки в файле
        if c:
            g = random.randint(1, p - 1)
            cb = random.randint(1, p - 1)
            k = random.randint(1, p - 2)
            db = powmod(g, cb, p)
            print("db =", db)
            #r = powmod(g, k, p)
            e = mul(powmod(db, k, p), c, p)
            print("e=",e)
            r = powmod(g, k, p)
            mobs.append(e)
            mobsg.append(g)
            mobscb.append(cb)
            mobsk.append(k)
            mobsr.append(r)
    
    print("ss",mobs)
```

Раскодирование:

```
for k in range(len(mobs)):
    deM = mul(mobs[k], powmod(mobsr[k], p - 1 - mobscb[k], p), p)
    print("Decrypted222 =", deM)
    qw=deM
    print(qw)
    mobqw.append(qw)
    fs = 'rez_eg.dat'
    with open(fs, "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(mobqw, file)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99974/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Comment: @AK, плохо что нет оповещения при переносе разговора. Я на следующий день потерял этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В конце программы для записи в бинарный файл вам нужно использовать метод `write`, а не `pickle.dump`. `pickle` сохраняет переданный ей объект (список чисел в данном случае) в собственном "сложном" формате (как минимум, каждое значение из списка в файле будет занимать больше байта), так чтобы при при последующем чтении с помощью `pickle.load` на выходе получить исходный список.

Вам нужно просто преобразовать список в байты, и записать в файл:

```
with open(fs, "wb") as file:
    file.write(bytes(mobqw))
```